# How to check splitted values of a column without changing the dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, sklearn-pandas, strsplit

I am trying to find columns hitting specific conditions and put a value in the column `col`.

My current implementation is:

```
df.loc[~(df['myCol'].isin(myInfo)), 'col'] = 'ok'
```

In the future, `myCol` will have multiple info. So I need to split the value in `myCol` without changing the dataframe and check if any of the splitted values are in myInfo. If one of them are, the current row should get the value 'ok' in the column col. Is there an elegant way without really splitting and saving in an extra variable?
Currently, I do not know how the multiple info will be represented (either separated by a character or just concatenated one after one, each consisting of 4 alphanumeric values).

Comment: could you add a sample desired df to your code? i m thinking of using list comprehension. something like `[x in myInfo for x in df['myCol'].str.split()]`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you need to split on "-" for your `myCol` column.

```
sep='-'
deconcat = df['MyCol'].str.split(sep, expand=True)
new_df=df.join(deconcat)
```

The `new_df` `DataFrame` will have the same index as `df`, therefore you can do what you want with `new_df` and then `join` back to `df` to filter it how you want.

You can do the above `.isin` code for each of the new split columns to get your desired result.

**Source:**
Code taken from the `pyjanitor` documentation which has a built-in function, [`deconcatenate_column`](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-janitor.functions), that does this.

Source code for [`deconcatenate_column`](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/_modules/janitor/functions.html#deconcatenate_column)